# ASP.NET using an Access database

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to create an Online CV and have stored all the info into an Access DB, I need help with this below error I get when I use an ASP button to create a label and then try to use the label to find the relevant info in te DB.

Below is my error

> ### Server Error in '/Interactive CV' Application.
>
> Syntax error in FROM clause.    Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
>   review the stack trace for more information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in
>   FROM clause.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 81:                 conn.Open() Line 82:                 'Declare
>   an OleDbDataReader to read the data in the database Line 83:
>   Using myReader As OleDbDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader() Line 84:
>   myReader.Read() Line 85:                     'Create a label
>
> Source File:  C:\Users\user\Desktop\Uni Final Module\Interactive
>   CV\File.aspx.vb    Line:  83
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [OleDbException (0x80040e14): Syntax error in FROM clause.]
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult
>   hr) +1081708
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS
>   dbParams, Object& executeResult) +247
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object&
>   executeResult) +194
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, Object& executeResult) +58
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method) +167
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   +116    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader() +6    File.createContent(String e) in C:\Users\user\Desktop\Uni Final
>   Module\Interactive CV\File.aspx.vb:83    File.btnContent_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\user\Desktop\Uni Final
>   Module\Interactive CV\File.aspx.vb:51
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +112
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +36    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +5563

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

Comment: Please improve your question - give it some format/structure and adding some of your code is a good start ;-)

Comment: @Mohammed Khalif- looks like your command string is not well formed. Can you post it also?

Answer (score 0):

Check your SQL Statement. 
Look like your table name ist wrong. Try something like select id, name from [Table Name] where Nr > 10